# Bug in Activity Tab Pagination

Tags: bug, documentation, user-interface

Pages 79 - 83 of the Activity Tab in [JavaScript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript?tab=activity&subtab=none&page=83) is blank while the pages 102 - 109 in [C# Language tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23?tab=activity&subtab=none&page=109) is blank

This seems to also occur in other tags.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how many items each page must contain, but looking at the number of actions on the javascript activity page it seems to me that this might be related:

- Page 1 contains 27 items.
- Page 2 contains 24 items.
- Page 3 contains 21 items.
- Page 4 contains 24 items.
- Page 5 contains 26 items.
- Page 6 contains 21 items.
- etc...

Comment: Go home Docs, you're drunk!